# Redirecting to the same page using jsp

Tags: jsp

I have one requirement in which I must create a **log in page** such way that if log in fails, user should be redirected to the same page with 'error message'.
I am only supposed to use JSP and javascript for validation.
Please suggest me something over it.
Thanks.

Comment: Too bad that you're restricted to JSP/JS. You *normally* use a servlet for this. See also the postprocessing part of this answer for hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can not check for login in same jsp page* so you need a processing page between home page and login page.

Make a processing page may be named as `authentication.jsp` now check for login in this page and if login gets successful redirect to home page and if login page fails redirect back to login page. you can use `response.redirect` or `<c:redirect>` to redirect to login page.